# Validation Message By Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation, devexpress

I have an question here. How to disable a validation when checkbox checked. i have tried ValidatorEnable(control, false) , it can't work for me.

```
<dxe:BaseCheckBox runat ="server" ID="chkIsChecked" ClientInstanceName ="chkIsChecked">
       <ClientSideEvents CheckedChanged="OnSelectionChanged"/>
</dxe:BaseCheckBox>


<dxe:BaseComboBox runat ="server" ID="cboLabour" ClientInstanceName ="cboLabour" ValueType="System.String" ClientEnabled="false"  >
     <ValidationSettings SetFocusOnError="True" ErrorText="This field is required to fill."
       ErrorDisplayMode="ImageWithTooltip" ValidationGroup="RejectReason"   
       CausesValidation="false">
          <RequiredField IsRequired="True" ErrorText="This field is required to fill.">
          </RequiredField>
     </ValidationSettings>
</dxe:BaseComboBox>
```

My Javascript:

```
function OnSelectionChanged(s,e)
{
    if(chkIsChecked.GetValue())
    {
        cboLabour.SetEnabled(true);
    }
    else
    {      
        cboLabour.SetEnabled(false);
        cboLabour.SetValue('');
    }
}
```

Thanks for Advice.

Comment: Since you're not using built-in controls you should specify which library these are from.  The answer depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you'll need to use custom validation.  Something like this:

```
function OnLabouryValidation(s, e) {
     if (chkIsChecked.GetValue())
         return;

     var v = e.value;
     if(e.value)
          return;

    e.isValid = false;
    e.errorText = "Required.";
}
```

There's "documentation" on custom validation here, but in my quick reading, it's not explicitly clear how to wire this up.

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument11135

Answer (score 0):

As i discovered from your question you are looking for the group validation:

First Set the ValidateOnLeave="False" in ValidationSettings and Specify the Validation group name to your controls and then use the client side `ASPxClientEdit.ValidateGroup('MyGroup');`method to validated your group of controls by doing your some customization as per your requirment.

Markup:

```
 <dxe:BaseCheckBox runat ="server" ID="chkIsChecked" ClientInstanceName ="chkIsChecked">
           <ClientSideEvents CheckedChanged="OnSelectionChanged"/>
    </dxe:BaseCheckBox>


    <dxe:BaseComboBox runat ="server" ID="cboLabour" ClientInstanceName ="cboLabour" ValueType="System.String" ClientEnabled="false"  >
         <ValidationSettings SetFocusOnError="True" ErrorText="This field is required to fill."
           ErrorDisplayMode="ImageWithTooltip" ValidationGroup="RejectReason"   
          ValidateOnLeave="False">
              <RequiredField IsRequired="True" ErrorText="This field is required to fill.">
              </RequiredField>
         </ValidationSettings>
    </dxe:BaseComboBox>


<dx:ASPxButton ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Validate" 
AutoPostBack="False" CausesValidation="False">

         <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {

    if (chkIsChecked.GetValue())  // if checked then validate the group
    {
              ASPxClientEdit.ValidateGroup('RejectReason');
    }
         }" />
    </dx:ASPxButton>
```

Follow these documentation and implement whatever you are trying to do.
[How to: Validate a Group of Editors](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument11132)
[How to: Validate All Editors on a Page](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument11133)
[How to: Implement a Custom Validation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument11135)
[ASPxClientEdit.Validation Event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientEdit_Validationtopic)

Comment: i added button clicked event in the btn which is OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" , after i clicked on the button , the page  validate the combobox successfully ,but it will fire the btnSubmit_click event.

Comment: have you used AutoPostBack="False" it will stop to postback