# Validate an aspxtextbox on aspxbutton using javascript

Tags: javascript, devexpress

How can I validate an aspxtexbox using javascript on button click. I am having a aspxtextbox and a aspxbutton, on click I need to check whether the textbox is empty or not if empty I need to show a confirmation box, on clicking cancel I need to set focus on the aspxtextbox

In general asp we write as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function checkEmpty() {
var subj= "";
subj= document.getElementById("txtString").value;
if(subj=="")
{

}
}
</Script>
```

How can I have this using Devex

Comment: Really really consider using something else as DevExpres components. Heay weight, hard to use, buggy and slow.

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

1. ASP.Net Validator controls. They support both Server-side and
   Client-side validation. CompareValidator or RegularExpressionValidator would suit your purpose. Refer this link on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/426761/Exploring-ASP-NET-Validation-Controls)
2. [JQuery Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate)
3. Custom JavaScript Validation - the simplest way would be to use the onSubmit event of the form. Taking your eg.

   <form onsubmit="javascript:checkEmpty()">...</form>

The validation script could look like:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function checkEmpty() {
    var subj = document.getElementById("txtString").value;
    if(subj=="")
    {
        subj.focus();
        alert("Error Message...");
        return false;
    }
}
</Script>
```

Comment: check my question clearly I am using devex tools not aspx controls

Comment: Ahh! My Bad! I took AspxTextBox for Asp.Net Textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Devexpress [online demo](http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxeditorsdemos/Validation/Inplace.aspx) shows how to add validations and customize them. Just keep SetFocusOnError checked in the demo.

You may also refer to [Devexpress online docs](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#silverlight/customdocument4920).

Hope this helps!

Vivek

Comment: I know this is not the perfect solution but the online docs should provide some help!

Answer (score 0):

If you skip showing popup message then DevExpress validation settings are better option and you can just validate the control client side by settings it's `ValidationGroup`.

Check my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9937271/770710) that may relevant to you on this SO thread - [Validation Message By Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935967/validation-message-by-javascript/9937271#9937271)

example:

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Validate" 
AutoPostBack="False" CausesValidation="False">

         <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {

    if (chkIsChecked.GetValue())  // if checked then validate the group
    {
              ASPxClientEdit.ValidateGroup('RejectReason');
    }
         }" />
    </dx:ASPxButton>
```

If you want to Show Popup Message then it's your work around. use the another answer

Set `ClientInstanceName` of the textBox and you will able to access it client side.

```
<dxe:ASPxTextBox ID="InstrumentQuantity" 
 runat="server" Width="170px" 
 ClientInstanceName="MyTextBox"> 
</dxe:ASPxTextBox>
```

Use the AxpxButton client click event and call the javascript method to perform your desired result of operation.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function checkEmpty() {

    var theText = MyTextBox.GetValue(); //GetValue() is the DevExpress clientside function
    if(theText =="")
    {
       //you pop message code and focus related work
    }
}
```

Refer [ASPxTextBox Client side methods and events](http://www.devexpress.com/Help/?document=ASPxEditors/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientTextBox_ctortopic.htm) for better help.